# SPFx Angular Elements with @pnp/spfx generator

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp

How we can enable Angular elements in SPFx webpart using @pnp/spfx generator?

[image]
**Installed Versions:**

[image: Versions:]
**After** "**npm list -g --depth 0**"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to install the angular CLI. If that is not installed, this option is disabled.

To install the CLI, you can do that as below:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Once installed, this option will be enabled.

**Update** - based on comments.

Looks like there is some sort of regression in the `1.9.0` version.

To use the angular elements with the latest version, you need to use an older version of Angular CLI as below:

```
npm install -g @pnp/generator-spfx @angular/cli@6.2.9
```

or

```
npm install -g @pnp/generator-spfx @angular/cli@7.3.9
```

Reference - [Angular elements in PnP SPFx generator](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/howtos/angularelements/)

Comment: I have already installed it but somehow not working

Comment: Did you install it globally ? Also try doing that in admin mode.

Comment: Yes i also added globally as an admin but not working

Comment: I have updated question and added screenshot for versions

Comment: can you post a screenshot after executing `npm list -g --depth 0` ?

Comment: never mind, looks like a regression in the latest version. Can you use the older version of the generator using `npm install -g @pnp/generator-spfx@1.8.1` and try

Comment: I have added screenshot

Comment: Not an issue. Let me check with downgrade version

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly after downgrading the version

Comment: Updated answer, looks like you can use the latest version of the generator, but the CLI needs to downgraded as mentioned in the answer ! Thanks for confirming, working on a fix :)

Comment: Yes, I got it :)